# Instalación de Docker con php local y php en el docker

Tags: php, laravel, php7, docker, docker-compose

Mi stack es **windows** + **docker** y tengo configurando mi docker-compose de esta forma para correr Laravel con apache + mysql, pero aparte de esto, tengo instalado como servicios apache2.4 + mysql 5.7 + php 7.2.30, a pesar de tenerlos instalados tengo los servicios parados.

Mi fichero **docker-compose** es este

```
version: '3.7'
services: 
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
    image: 'laravelapp'
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'laraapp_db'
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ""
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
```

Y mi fichero dockerfile, sin embargo es este

```
FROM php:7.4.1-apache

USER root

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libpng-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libonig-dev \
        zip \
        curl \
        unzip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && docker-php-source delete

COPY .docker/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html \
    && a2enmod rewrite
```

El problema lo tengo cuando ejecuto un comando para instalar passport en laravel. Me dice que mi versión de php no es válida porque es la 7.2.30, que es la versión que tengo en local no la del docker

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. Has hecho dos preguntas correlacionadas. Y, por lo que veo necesitas que el mySql ligado a laravel corra en otro puerto. Descarga [Bitnami Wamp-Stack](https://bitnami.com/stack/wamp) Viene con laravel (para activarlo basta descomentar una línea en conf) y puedes hacer n instalaciones simultáneas en el mismo equipo sin que los servidores MySql se pisen.

Comment: Hay varias maneras de hacerlo, una puede ser accediendo al bash del servicio `app` que tiene php-apache `docker-compose exec --user 1000 app /bin/bash`, y tendrás una consola para ejecutar composer y los comandos artisan desde dentro del contenedor. Si no correr un comando en un servicio una sola vez con[docker-compose run app ...](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/).